# Extract blob data to file system

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, blob, filenet

I have large amount of files(approx 80000) stored into sql server database as `BLOB`. Now I have a situation where I need to export all those file in blob to IBM Filenet.

For that what I think that first I need to stream those existing blob data into file system and then I will use filenet for uploading those file into filenet server.

Now please help me writing a C# utility which will convert those huge blob data into corresponding files.

Comment: -1 What is your question and what have you tried? If you want us to write a problem, SOF is not your codegenerator...

Answer (score 0):

You can be [Managing FILESTREAM Data by Using Win32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645940%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) API.

This link contains C# code that loads BLOB into a variable in you C# code. Then you can save it with path, file name and extention derrived from DB as well. Here is a a small quote of code:

```
//Read the data from the FILESTREAM
//BLOB.
sqlFileStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);

numBytes = sqlFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

string readData = unicode.GetString(buffer);

if (numBytes != 0)
    Console.WriteLine(readData);
```

See also [Using FILESTREAM Storage in Client Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933877%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).